# XPages view filtered by date range works perfectly until user returns to the view

Tags: date, filter, xpages

I have an XPage with two date fields and a repeat control bound to a view. When a date is selected in each date field my code creates a date range and uses the "keys" parameter of the view to return only the docs in the view between the two dates. This works perfectly. The problem arises when one navigates away from the view then returns. I have a pagerSaveState control which should restore the view to the state it was in when one navigates back to the view, but instead an error occurs: `com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector`

The XML for the view looks like this:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="ByDeliveryDate"
        keysExactMatch="true"
        keys="#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedDateRange}">

    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
```

The SSJS that creates the date range and puts it into the sessionScope variable looks like this:

```
function doDateRangeSearch() {

var vValStart = @Date(getComponent('StartDate').getValue());
if(vValStart==null||vValStart=='')vValStart = @Date(@Year(@Today()),1,1,0,0,0);

var vValEnd = @Date(getComponent('EndDate').getValue());
if(vValEnd==null||vValEnd=='')vValEnd = @Today();

var vDateRange = session.createDateRange(vValStart, vValEnd);
var vDateVector:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
vDateVector.addElement(vDateRange);
if(vDateVector.isEmpty())vDateVector = null;

sessionScope.selectedStartDate = vValStart;
sessionScope.selectedEndDate = vValEnd;
sessionScope.selectedDateRange = vDateVector;

/* reset the pager to the first page because if there is only one search 
 * result to display and if the pager was on anything except the first 
 * page the search result is not displayed
 */
var pager:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspPager = getComponent("pager1"); 
pager.gotoPage(0);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why returning to the view causes this error?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Panu, I added the following code to the queryOpen event of the view:

```
print("queryOpen: opening date range view");
if(sessionScope.selectedDateRange == null){
    print("selectedDateRange is null")
}else{
    for (var s in sessionScope.selectedDateRange) print(s);
}
print("queryOpen: completed");
```

In my web browser I navigated to the view. The view displays with the latest documents on the first page because this is the first time I am visiting the view in this session. This is what appeared on the console:
18/10/2013 10:45:23   HTTP JVM: queryOpen: opening date range view
18/10/2013 10:45:23   HTTP JVM: selectedDateRange is null
18/10/2013 10:45:23   HTTP JVM: queryOpen: completed

Next I selected some dates in the two date fields and clicked the button which calls my SSJS function. The search was performed correctly and only the documents in the date range were displayed. This is what appeared on the console:
18/10/2013 10:45:48   HTTP JVM: queryOpen: opening date range view
18/10/2013 10:45:48   HTTP JVM: 01/08/2013 00:00:00 GDT - 18/10/2013 00:00:00 GDT
18/10/2013 10:45:48   HTTP JVM: queryOpen: completed

I clicked on one of the documents to open it, then went back to the view. I was shown the error page instead. This is what appeared on the console:
18/10/2013 10:46:16   HTTP JVM: queryOpen: opening date range view
18/10/2013 10:46:16   HTTP JVM: null
18/10/2013 10:46:16   HTTP JVM: queryOpen: completed
18/10/2013 10:46:16   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector

Based on the above it looks like sessionScope.selectedDateRange still exists but has lost all its content.

Comment: Why do you use a Vector? 
Did you try to save the vDateRange directly to sessionScope.selecteDateRange? 

How does the first column on the view look like, that means, what kind of data is there? DateTime values? Strings? 

I'm surprised that it works in the first place.

Comment: The first column of the view is a date column containing DateTime values.

Comment: and what about the Vector? Did you try without the Vector?

Comment: I use a vector because the keys property of the view requires a vector. I save vDateRange directly into the sessionScope.selectedDateRange variable in the 9th line from the bottom of the function above. The first column of the view is a date column containing DateTime values. I was also surprised it worked! It would be great if only users could navigate away from the view and back to it! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Did you try without the Vector?". I have to supply an array of values to the keys property and, as far as I know, a vector is a type of array.

Comment: you could use sessionScope.selectedDateRange=[vDateRange] - this would store the daterange as native array. It's just an idea to try.

Comment: What's in the Vector when you get this error?

Comment: @JulianBuss - I tried the `[vDateRange]` tip as you suggested. It gives the same results as the vector, ie. it displays the first page of results without problem but navigating away from the view and then returning to it throws the same error. Thanks for the tip, though. At least it has made my code a bit shorter :)

Comment: @PanuHaaramo - As far as I know the Vector contains an array of dates.

Comment: I've just realised the pager doesn't work either. I had not noticed this before. (It makes no difference to the pager whether I use the vector or Julian's array suggestion. It does not work in either case).

Comment: yes, it really seems to be an issue with the sessionScope. Perhaps it is overwritten when the page reloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working. Thanks to Julian and Panu for their suggestions. The following is how I solved the problem. I'm posting it here in case anyone else ever wants to do a similar thing.

First, create a view where the first sorted column contains the dates. Make it a Date/Time column.

Second, on the custom control that displays your view, add two date fields like so:

**start date field:**

```
<xe:djDateTextBox
    id="StartDate"
    defaultValue="#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedStartDate}"
    value="#{sessionScope.selectedStartDate}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
            dateStyle="full">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xe:djDateTextBox>
```

**end date field:**

```
<xe:djDateTextBox
    id="EndDate"
    defaultValue="#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedEndDate}"
    value="#{sessionScope.selectedEndDate}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
            dateStyle="full">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xe:djDateTextBox>
```

Note that the fields are bound to sessionScope variables.

Third, add a data source to your custom control:

```
<xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="ByDeliveryDate"
            keysExactMatch="true">

            <xp:this.keys><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
    if(sessionScope.selectedStartDate == null) return;
    if(sessionScope.selectedStartDate == "") return;
    if(sessionScope.selectedEndDate == null) return;
    if(sessionScope.selectedEndDate == "") return;

    var vDateRange = session.createDateRange(sessionScope.selectedStartDate, sessionScope.selectedEndDate);
    return [vDateRange]

}catch(e){
    print("view filter error: " + e.toString())
}}]]></xp:this.keys>
        </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
```

Last, add a button that does nothing but refreshes the view:

```
<xp:button value="Go" id="FirstColumnSearchButton"
    styleClass="lotusBtn goButton">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
        submit="false" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewHolder">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

If you want, you can also add a "Reset" button to restore the view to its original state:

```
<xp:button value="Reset"
    id="FirstColumnSearchResetButton">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
        submit="false" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viewHolder">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.selectedStartDate = "";
sessionScope.selectedEndDate = "";}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Note that it does NOT use the `doDateRangeSearch()` function that I posted in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

To debug place this code as the first line of your `keys` parameter:

```
print(sessionScope.selectedDateRange);
```

You could also try these:

```
for (var s in sessionScope.selectedDateRange) print(s);
for (var s in sessionScope.selectedDateRange) print(typeof s);
```

This way you will see what is in the Vector when you get the error.

Probabaly the DateRange is gone from the sessionScope and you will need to place it there again. You can place it in the `keys` parameter if needed.

**Update**

As you found out your date range dissappears from sessionScope. That happens because `DateRange` is a `lotus.domino` object. They are not serializable and will not stay in scoped variables. As a workaround you can store the dates to sessionScope as `java.util.Date` (or `Calendar`) and create the `DateRange` based on those each time the page is accessed.